# Cross Reference Enumeration from a Different Document

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I'm working on a Design document that is based on a Requirements document that is subject to change. The Design document must reference Requirements in an enumerated list from the Requirements Document.

My requirements document has something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Requirement 1  \label{Req1}
    \item Requirement 2:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Requirement 2a \label{Req2a}
        \item Requirement 2b \label{Req2b}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

My design document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm ,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}

\begin{document}
\externaldocument{../requirements/Requirements.tex}

\section{Functional Requirements}
Functional Requirements are things the system must do. These are: \\

\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
    \hline
    Requirement & Subsystem(s) implementing the requirement \\ \hline
    \ref{Req1} & Graphical Front End \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to see the number that is given to the item in the enumeration show up in the \ref{Req1} space. But what I see now are two question marks. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your requirement document, add `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{enumerate}`. The `enumerate` package will write the label to auxiliary file. Then only we will able to call it in the design file. The `hyperref` package is needed, since you have used this package in the design file. Otherwise you will end up in error while compiling second file.

Also put `\externaldocument` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting some extraneous section information included in the reference as well as the enumeration number. I'm asking another question about that though.